# Is it possible to enable ion-scroll on background image?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I wonder if there is a way to be able to scroll to the rest of the background-image since i've been using `background-size : cover;` and the background i'm using is way bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply it with the CSS class or style on ion-content tag editing height of background-size to size in pixels(background-size: 100% 902px), like:

```js
<ion-content style="background: url('../assets/img/bg.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: 100% 902px;" padding>
```